# Txt file input error Java

Tags: java

I'm getting the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "scores.txt"
at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1222)
at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:510)
at ExamAverage.main(ExamAverage.java:30)
 C:\Users\Peter\AppData\Local\Temp\codecomp5461808896109186034.xml:312: Java returned: 1
```

for my code listed below what does this error mean? I'm trying to go line by line from a given text file path and output it in a certain format.

```
       import java.io.FileReader;
      import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
      import java.util.Scanner;
      import java.io.PrintWriter;

      public class ExamAverage
     {

     public static void main(String[] args)
  throws FileNotFoundException
  {
  String inputFileName = "scores.txt";
  String outputFileName = "examScoreAverage.txt";
  Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
  Scanner in = new Scanner(inputFileName);
  PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(outputFileName);
  int TestNumber = 1;
  double totalPoints = 0;
  double avg = 0;
  double test = 0;

    while (in.hasNextLine())
    {
       String line = in.nextLine();
          test = Double.parseDouble(line);
       out.println("Score" + TestNumber + " : " + test);
       totalPoints += test;
       TestNumber++;
    }
       avg = totalPoints/TestNumber;
       out.println("Number of scores read: " + TestNumber );
       out.println("Average Score " + avg );
   in.close();
out.close();
```

}
}

Comment: Show the contents of `scores.txt`. Maybe not all the lines in the file contain numbers, so `parseDouble` was unable to convert a line's "contents" into a number.

Comment: The contents of `scores.txt` are irrelevant since in no way are the contents of that file being read or parsed ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html

It appears you think you can pass a filename to `Scanner` and have it open it.
There is no constructor for `Scanner` that takes a file name as an argument in the way you think. What you have is a scanner that is reading over the `String` "scores.txt"

The JavaDocs show you how to use the `Scanner` class properly to read in a file:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(inputFileName));
```

Comment: Forgive me if I may be asking a stupid question. I'm still in my first level Comp Sci class, but not i keep getting the error `ExamAverage.java:19: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class File
location: class ExamAverage
      Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("inputFileName"));
                                   ^`

Comment: You may want to read the Oracle tutorial for Scanning: http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html - the second example shows how to do exactly what you're trying to do (read `double`s from a text file). Your new error is because you aren't importing `java.io.File`

Comment: Thanks for the help! Sometimes when learning this I can be a little overwhelming.

Comment: No worries - that's what SO is for :)

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
test = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

trys to create a double from the line variable. The error you are getting is because there is something other than a number in the line variable. Try printing out line before you call `parseDouble()`

Comment: The "something other" is ... his filename.

Comment: Well really it doesn't matter what "something other" is. Only that it isn't a number

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to format a number from a string datatype.  The java runtime are showing you the problem: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "scores.txt"

I didn't run the code, but debug it and cast the string number value to the correct datatype number format and it will work.

Answer (score 0):

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "scores.txt"

Looks like in the following:

```
test = Double.parseDouble(line);
```

`line` contains `"scores.txt"` instead of the content of the file.

Answer (score 0):

Your in Scanner is not reading from the  text file, it is actually reading the string literal "scores.txt" and then trying to parse "scores.txt" as a double. When constructing the Scanner to read from the file, make sure you pass a File, not the name of the file. It would look something like this:

> `Scanner in = new Scanner(new File("./scores.txt")):`

Just make sure you pass the correct file path to File, not just the file name.